# Подскажите. Возникает ошибка "Call to a member function getOneTask() on null при передаче данных по AJAX в symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony

Всем доброго дня. Делаю первые шаги в symfonу .Прошу помощи по вопросу
Контроллер

```
 /**
     * @Route("/profile/task/update", name="user_task_update")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
            $taskId = $request->get('Edit_id');
            

            $task = $this->taskRepository->getOneTask($taskId);    //здесь ошибка
            $task->setDraft();
            $this->taskRepository->setUpdateTask($task);
        
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_task');
    }
```

JS

```
function edit_task(){
    $(document).on('click','#btn_edit',function()
    {
        var Edit_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('#update').modal('show');
        $(document).on('click','#btn_update', function(){
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'profile/task/update',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {Edit_id:Edit_id},
                })
        })
    })
}
```

В консоли Edit_id есть, то есть данные передаются. Но в контроллере возникает ошибка.

Comment: Ну очевидно у вас нет $this->taskRepository 
У вас версия наверняка достаточно свежая, по сему вам стоит инжектить нужные вам сервисы (в вашем случае репозиторий) через сигнатуру метода  update . Ну в случае если у вас правильно оформлен тот самый репозиторий, чтоб его видел service container

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Я почему то подумал, что аргумент функции getOneTask($taskId) пустой и поэтому ошибка

Comment: Вопрос решен добавлением в контроллер конструктора с одной строчкой $this->taskRepository = $taskRepository;  и всё.